# Saving a text field/area to a text file

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a program that saves the contents of four text fields and a text area and saves them to a text file when the "Send" button is clicked. The output should look something like this:

```
To: [Text Field]
CC: [Second Text Field]
Bcc: [Third Text Field]
Subject: [Fourth Text Field]
Message:
[Text Area]
```

For example, the first line of the text file will have "To: ", the contents of a text field, and will then skip to the next line.

Although my program compiles, the text file remains blank. I've tried everything I can think of, but can't seem to figure out the cause. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EmailProg extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel panNorth;
    private JPanel panCenter;
    private JPanel panSouth;

    private JLabel toLabel;
    private JLabel ccLabel;
    private JLabel bccLabel;
    private JLabel subLabel;
    private JLabel msgLabel;

    private JTextField toField;
    private JTextField ccField;
    private JTextField bccField;
    private JTextField subField;
    private JTextArea msgArea;

    private JButton send;


    public EmailProg() {
        setTitle("Compose Email");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panNorth = new JPanel();
        panNorth.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("To:");
        panNorth.add(toLabel);
        JTextField toField = new JTextField(15);
        panNorth.add(toField);
        JLabel ccLabel = new JLabel("CC:");
        panNorth.add(ccLabel);
        JTextField ccField = new JTextField(15);
        panNorth.add(ccField);
        JLabel bccLabel = new JLabel("Bcc:");
        panNorth.add(bccLabel);
        JTextField bccField = new JTextField(15);
        panNorth.add(bccField);
        JLabel subLabel = new JLabel("Subject:");
        panNorth.add(subLabel);
        JTextField subField = new JTextField(15);
        panNorth.add(subField);
        add(panNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panCenter = new JPanel();
        panCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        JLabel msgLabel = new JLabel("Message:");
        panCenter.add(msgLabel);
        JTextArea msgArea = new JTextArea(5, 15);
        panCenter.add(msgArea);
        add(panCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panSouth = new JPanel();
        panSouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.addActionListener(this);
        panSouth.add(send);
        add(panSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                //Write labels and corresponding fields to text file
                BufferedWriter outfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("email.txt"));
                outfile.write("To: ");
                outfile.write(toField.getText());
                //repeat for CC, Bcc, and Subject labels/fields, and for Message label/text area


            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }
            catch(NullPointerException j){
                System.out.println("Null.");
            }
            catch(IOException k){
                System.out.println("IO Exception.");            
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Saved");
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmailProg win = new EmailProg();
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.pack();
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
outfile.write(toField.getText());
```

if causing the application to enter the `NullPointerException` code block. This is because the variable `toField` is not set.

To fix, you can to remove the `JTextField` keyword from the declaration of `toField` to in your constructor to assign it to the class member variable:

```
toField = new JTextField(15);
```

Similarly for the other components in the application that you may need outside the scope of the constructor:

```
    ccLabel = new JLabel("CC:");
    ccField = new JTextField(15);
    // etc.
```

Also another important note—don't forget to close the output stream after writing, otherwise any data that was buffered to be written will *not* be written to disk.

```
outfile.close();
```

Comment: I removed JTextField and similar keywords from the constructor, but the text file is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

Change `JTextField toField = new JTextField(15);` to `toField = new JTextField(15);`. This will initialize your class member variable instead of creating a new local variable.

Since you have redefined it, the class level variable(`toField`) being used in `actionPerformed()` is not coming as initialized and hence the issue.